# PHP / MYSQL - define variables with IF, ELSE?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement

I am writing a simple web program with PHP / MYSQL (due to limitations, mysql queries must be used rather than mysqli or PDO).  An HTML table must display different values from my MYSQL table based on user form input.

What is the best way to define several variables based on the user input?

I tried

```
<?php
$taxcode = $_POST['taxcode'];

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = 'root';

$database = 'database';
$table = 'sampletable';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

    if ($taxcode = '401(k)') {
    $planquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE PT_401k = '401(k)'");
    $orgmatchquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution (i.e., 50% of first 6% of pay)' AND PT_401k = '401(k)'");
    } elseif ($taxcode = '403(b)') {
    $planquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE PT_403b = '403(b)'");
    $orgmatchquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution (i.e., 50% of first 6% of pay)' AND PT_403b = '403(b)'");
    } elseif ($taxcode = '457') {
    $planquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE PT_457 = '457'");
    $orgmatchquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution (i.e., 50% of first 6% of pay)' AND PT_457 = '457'");
    }

?>
```

but it's not changing the value based on the input. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT, per @Demodave's answer - this seems to be moving in the right direction but not quite working.

```
<?php

$taxcode = '401(k)';

    if ($taxcode == '401(k)' || $taxcode == '403(b)' || $taxcode == '457') {

    if($taxcode == '401(k)') {
        $where = "PT_401k"; 
    } else if($taxcode == '403(b)') {
        $where = "PT_403b";
    } else if($taxcode == '457') {
        $where = "PT_457";
    }

    echo $planquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $taxcode . "'");
    echo "<br />" . $orgmatchquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution (i.e., 50% of first 6% of pay)' AND " . $where . " = '" . $taxcode . "'");   

    }

?>
```

Getting errors that $where is undefined. Is it "legal" to use a variable for a row name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some repeating elements try doing this.

```
<?php

$taxcode = '401(k)'; // This is only an example for the POST variable.

if ($taxcode == '401(k)' || $taxcode == '403(b)' || $taxcode == '457') {

if($taxcode == '401(k)') {
    $where = "PT_401k"; 
} else if($taxcode == '403(b)') {
    $where = "PT_403b";
} else if($taxcode == '457') {
    $where = "PT_457";
}

echo $planquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $taxcode . "'");
echo "<br />" . $orgmatchquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution (i.e., 50% of first 6% of pay)' AND " . $where . " = '" . $taxcode . "'");   

}

?>
```

Output:

> SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE PT_401k = '401(k)'
>
> SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution (i.e., 50% of first 6% of pay)' AND PT_401k = '401(k)'

Comment: this looks promising but I'm getting errors:  Notice: Undefined variable: where in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/benchmark/step2.php on line 86 (seems like the "where" variable)

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/benchmark/step2.php on line 93

Comment: I'm defining $where with = '' the question is did you include the if ($taxcode == '401(k)' || $taxcode == '403(b)' || $taxcode == '457') { line because otherwise if the taxcode is not one of those number $where would never get defined.

Comment: yes; but should be irrelevant because that user input is a select dropdown with only three options. Are we sure that $where (or any variable) can be used in that case? Added an edit above.

Comment: It's just a variable name, use a different word than $where if you want, but the same result should occur, try the above example by itself.

Comment: Did you make sure that you are comparing ( == )  and not assigning ( = ) the items? Post your updated code. Make sure your form's method is post.

Comment: Hmm, you're correct, that example is yielding the correct output...must be some other conflict, I'll keep testing :)

Comment: Got it working! Your answer was correct, it was an error on my end - values on my form options were missing parentheses, i.e. "401k" instead of "401(k)".

Comment: @grownupteeth, if you remove the parentheses, you can remove the $where and make it WHERE PT_" . $taxcode . "

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by doing:

```
if ($taxcode = '401(k)') {
```

you are assigning values to a variable. You need to write:

```
if ($taxcode == '401(k)') {
```

Other than that, you probably want to build that query dynamically. Does that help?